# How to deal with conflicting function names in JavaScript if functions are from external JavaScript libraries?

Tags: javascript

I have two external JavaScript lib files I have to load on same [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) page. They both have a function called "autoSave()", both without parameters. I cannot modify their signature as they are not my script files.

How can I call a function in script A or script B explicitly? How is the precedence decided?

Comment: I found a function that can be used to generate a list of conflicting function names for two objects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15330156/975097

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function defined by the second script will overwrite the function defined by the first one.

You can save a copy of the function from script A before including script B.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script A"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoSave_A = autoSave;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Script B"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoSave_B = autoSave;
</script>
```

Note, by the way, that if script A calls `autoSave` by name, the script will call the wrong `autoSave` and (probably) stop working.
You could solve that by swapping in the `autoSave` functions before calling functions from either script using wrapper methods.

Answer (score 2):

Well, IMO your libraries should be *namespaced*, so you could easily call `lib1.autoSave()` or `lib2.autoSave(arg)`.

The goal is to use as [few global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript) as possible.

Give a look to the following articles:

- [Namespacing your JavaScript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/)
- [JavaScript Namespacing](http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing)

Comment: Yes, but he cannot modify the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A second function declaration for the same function name overwrites an earlier one, so it will depend on the order your scripts are included.