# Find conflicting method names in two JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to simulate multiple inheritance in JavaScript, so I need to find a way to obtain a list of conflicting method names for two JavaScript objects. Is it possible to generate a list of function names for two objects, and then find all of the function names that are the same between the two classes?

```
    function base1(){
        this.printStuff = function(){
            return "Implemented by base1";
        };
    }

    function base2(){
        this.printStuff = function(){
            return "Implemented by base2";
        };
    }

function getConflictingFunctionNames(object1, object2){
    //get a list of conflicting function names between the two objects. 

    //to be implemented.
}

console.log(getConflictingFunctionNames(base1, base2)); //this should print ["printStuff"]
```

Comment: Why would it print `"object1", "object2"`?

Comment: I think I'll need to get a list of all methods in each object, as described here, and then find all the method names that are the same in both of them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257993/how-to-display-all-methods-in-a-javascript-object

Comment: @ExplosionPills I fixed the mistake. I meant to write `"printstuff"`.

Comment: You don't need to get all the methods of both objects, you just need to get the methods of one object and check which ones the other object has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to follow the following steps:

1. Get all the own property names on each object.
2. Filter the functions.
3. Create a union of both the sets.

The first two steps can be combined into a single function:

```
function getOwnFunctionNames(object) {
    var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
    var length = properties.length;
    var functions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var property = properties[i];
        if (typeof object[property] === "function")
            functions.push(property);
    }

    return functions;
}
```

Next you need to find the union of the set of functions of two objects:

```
function getConflictingFunctionNames(object1, object2) {
    var functions1 = getOwnFunctionNames(object1);
    var functions2 = getOwnFunctionNames(object2);
    var length = functions1.length;
    var functions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var functionName = functions1[i];
        if (functions2.indexOf(functionName) >= 0)
            functions.push(functionName);
    }

    return functions;
}
```

Now you may do whatever you wish with these functions.

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/gVCNd/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the common named methods, then:

```
function getCommonNamedMethods(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = [];

  for (var p in obj1) {

    if (typeof obj1[p] == 'function' && typeof obj2[p] == 'function' ) {
      result.push(p);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

If you want only own properties of the objects, include an own properties test:

```
function getCommonNamedMethods(obj1, obj2) {
  var result = [];

  for (var p in obj1) {

    if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj1[p] == 'function' &&
        obj2.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof obj2[p] == 'function' ) {
       result.push(p);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```