# Import two different libraries with two identical function names

Tags: javascript, function, package, shared-libraries

I have a problem importing my libraries. I import my project like this into another project:

```
<app-root></app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/styles.bundle.js"></script>
```

There are 2 libraries with the same function name: forEach (collection, iteratee).

This overwrites the function I want to use. How can I do ? Knowing that I can not change the order of the libraries.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975793/how-to-deal-with-conflicting-function-names-in-javascript-if-functions-are-from

Comment: Yes but I can't modify thre script.

Comment: You don't need to modify it, just import one, save the function that you want to keep under a different name, then import the second one which will override the first function (but you don't care because you saved it under a different name).

Comment: Yes, but I do not see how to do it because I import all my libraries in one line, like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/chat/styles.bundle.js"></script>
`

Comment: Then may be there is a bug in the script. Is it a known library or something you have done yourself?

Comment: No, it's two known libraries. The function I want to use is in typescript.js and the one I do not want to use is in lodash.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152652/discussion-between-isma-c-and-floriane).

Answer (score 0):

posting for other people asking, this thread provides the solution:

[Load external library from CDN under an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802918/load-external-library-from-cdn-under-an-alias)