# Load external library from CDN under an alias

Tags: javascript, cdn

I need to load two versions of the same library from CDN. Is there a way to specify the name of the resulting object on `window` so that they don't clash? Or can I rename the first before the second loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="lib@1" />
<script> window.lib1 = window.lib; </script>
<script src="lib@2" />
```

then

```
window.lib1 // is lib@1
window.lib  // is lib@2
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way? Aren't you assigning the result of `src=lib1` to `window.lib2` in your code here?

Comment: What about async/defer? Can that be handled?

Comment: @Qwerty I think if you defer EVERY script element above, they execute in order after the rest of the page loads, so that should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Based on *Jonas Wilms*' answer, I came up with these two solutions when using webpack, which I have not mentioned in the original question.

here is a Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-library-versions-kvg5d

### webpack - [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

- you must change webpack config when updating a package

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    react: 'React16_11'
  }
};
```

in code

```
import React from 'react' // webpack translates to window.React16_11
```

### webpack - [aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575809/how-to-use-a-library-from-a-cdn-in-a-webpack-project-in-production)*

- you must change a .js file in project when updating a package

```
module.exports = {
  alias: {
    react$: './getReactFromWindow',
  },
};
```

getReactFromWindow.js:

```
 module.exports = window.React16_11;
```

in code

```
import React from 'react' // webpack translates to './getReactFromWindow'
```

*<sub>*webpack aliases based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575809/how-to-use-a-library-from-a-cdn-in-a-webpack-project-in-production)</sub>*