# How to restore Textbox Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small requirement,

We have restore the textbox data that was cleared previously.
Below is my HTMl code

```
<table>
   <tr><td><input type="textbox"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JQuery Code

```
       $('TABLE TR TD').find(':checkbox').change(function()
        {
            if($(this).prop('checked'))
            {
               $(this).parents('TR').siblings('TR').find('input').val("")
            }
            if(!$(this).prop('checked'))
            {
               $(this).parents('TR').siblings('TR').find('input').val(?)
            }
        });
```

My Requirement is to clear the textbox content if checkbox is checked. And if i deselect it the textbox should be restored with previous data.

Please someone help me.

Comment: use global variable or hidden fields to solve the problem

Comment: Where's the 'previous data' supposed to come from; is it a value the user enters, or from a `value` attribute?

Comment: Is there only one textbox/checkbox pair?

Comment: `type="textbox"` is not valid for [`<input>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4). It should just be `type="text"`

Comment: I've updated my demo based on your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595321/keydown-event-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a global variable to store the previous data -

```
var prevData;
```

then modify your code this way -

```
$('TABLE TR TD').find(':checkbox').change(function()
{
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        var $element = $(this).parents('TR').siblings('TR').find('input')
        prevData = $element.val();
        $element.val("");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parents('TR').siblings('TR').find('input').val(prevData);
    }
});
```

Comment: btw. the 'onChange' event should be never associated to a radio or checkbox field. Some browsers will go into trouble. Use 'onClick' instead.

Comment: @reporter: jQuery fixes those sorts of browser issues.

Comment: @patrick And yet you can make it for jquery easier if you write 'correct code' first. ;-)

Comment: @reporter, any chance you could cite a source for that comment? It's not something I've come across before (please note that I'm not disagreeing with you, but I'd be interested to learn more about it, particularly since my own posted answer relies on the `change()` method too).

Comment: @David 1st That's my own experience 2nd I know it from other users they went into trouble with this event. 3rd Unfortunatly I have only a german/french source. On this page the author(s) has written that the InternetExplorer has got a bug that he fires this too earlie so the state change won't be transfer to the DOM tree.

Comment: @reporter: thank you for heads-up! I'll try and keep an eye out for an English-language discussion on the subject =)

Answer (score 1):

When the checkbox is being checked, before clearing the value, store it using the jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) API.

```
<table>
   <tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>

$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var input = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="text"]');

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        input.data('text', input.val());
        input.val('');
    } else {
        input.val(input.data('text'));
    }
});
```

[**A demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcCbW/) which works if there were multiple pairs, so long as they exist in separate `<table>` parents. You could change the finder to get the previous sibling if that were not the case. This uses no global variables which are not really best practice - [How to avoid global variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript).

**Edit:** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcCbW/1/) based on your other question [Keydown event is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595321/keydown-event-is-not-working-properly) but this will only for key events and not if someone pastes text into the `<input>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something a little less reliant on the mark-up remaining the same (though it *does* require that the checkbox follows the text input):

```
var prevData, textInputIndex;
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        thisIndex = ($(this).index('table input') - 1);
        textInput = $('table input').eq(thisIndex);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            prevData = $(textInput).eq(thisIndex).val();
            $(textInput).eq(thisIndex).val('');
        }
        else {
            $(textInput).eq(thisIndex).val(prevData);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PWbm9/).

---

**Edited** to remove the problem of having only one variable to store the text-input value:

```
var $textInputs = $('table input:text');
var prevData, textInputIndex, affectedTextInputIndex, textInputValues = [];

$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        affectedTextInputIndex = $(this).index('table input') - 1;
        textInputIndex = $('table input').eq(affectedTextInputIndex).index('table input:text');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            textInputValues[textInputIndex] = $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val();
            $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val('');
        }
        else {
            $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val(textInputValues[textInputIndex]);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PWbm9/1/).

---

**Edited** to remove the explicit requirement that the `input` elements be contained in a `table`:

```
var $textInputs = $('input:text');
var prevData, textInputIndex, affectedTextInputIndex, textInputValues = [];

$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        affectedTextInputIndex = $(this).index('input') - 1;
        textInputIndex = $('ul input').eq(affectedTextInputIndex).index('input:text');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            textInputValues[textInputIndex] = $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val();
            $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val('');
        }
        else {
            $textInputs.eq(textInputIndex).val(textInputValues[textInputIndex]);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PWbm9/2/).

---

References:

- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).