# Pass an arbitrary number of parameters into a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code is barely an Ajax request that expects XML to be returned from back-end. The back-end can return `execute_callback` as one of XML tags like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<response>
    <execute_callback>
        <function_name>someFunction</function_name>
    </execute_callback>
</response>
```

And everything is okay as far as you know the exact number of parameters this `callback` expects. But what if the back-end has returned

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<response>
    <execute_callback>
        <function_name>someFunction</function_name>
        <param>10.2</param>
        <param>some_text</param>
    </execute_callback>
    <execute_callback>
        <function_name>otherFunction</function_name>
        <param>{ x: 1, y: 2 }</param>
    </execute_callback>
</response>
```

How do I now pass parameters 10.2 and 'some_text' to `someFunction` and JSON { x: 1, y: 2 } to `otherFunction`?

I know an ugly solution (using function's `arguments`), but I am looking for a pretty one.

And before I forget: don't parse the XML for me - I can do that on my own :) All I need is somewhat of a trick to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a function in JavaScript. If you know [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), I want:

```
def somefunc(x, y):
    print x, y
args = { 'x' : 1, 'y' : 2 }
somefunc(**args)
```

but in JavaScript.

Comment: How do you tell the difference between a literal—such as 10.2 and "some text" — and an expression that needs to be evaluated, such as `{ x: 1, y: 2 }`?

Comment: @RobG this does not concerns question. Example is always just an example. First thought: I will pass `type` attribute to `<param>`. It's not a problem at all to understand what type is returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could refer to [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply). Assuming the callback functions are declared in global object (`window` in browser).

```
var callback_function = window[function_name];
if (callback_function) { // prevent from calling undefined functions
    callback_function.apply(window, params);  // params is an array holding all parameters
}
```

Comment: +1 - I think this is the best method, though likely should be protected by `if (window[function_name])...`. But how to tell literals from identifiers and expressions? I guess they are all passed as strings and the called function works it out.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I'm looking for. By the way, I prefer `if (typeof fn == 'function') {`

Answer (score 9):

You can just pass them all into your function:

```
function someFunction(){
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        alert(arguments[i]);
}
```

Javascript functions have an arguments array-like object, and it is syntactically correct to call a javascript function with any number of arguments.

```
someFunction(1, 2, 'test', ['test', 'array'], 5, 0);
```

is a valid call to that function.

Comment: Oh haha, I don't think it's that ugly :)

Comment: Arguments is not an array, it's an arguments object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the function, reference your function as an element in an associative array by name:

```
var funcName = // parse your xml for function name
var params = new Array();
params[0] = 10.2; // from your parsed xml
params[1] = 'some text'; // also from your parsed xml

// functions are attached to some Object o:

o[funcName](params); // equivalent to o.funcName(params);
```

I wrote an example of the above here: http://jsbin.com/ewuqur/2/edit

Comment: `function somefunc(x,y) { alert(x+y); }` I want to pass ['a', 'b']. `somefunc.apply(window, ['a', 'b'])` -> "ab". `window['somefunc'](['a','b'])` -> "abundefined". Odd :-(

Comment: @Nemoden:  That's not what I said to do.  apply is not necessary.  http://jsbin.com/ewuqur/2/edit

Comment: to use Function.apply is yet another approach and it works. I just compared it with your method which has produced unexpected result.

Comment: @Nemoden, your second example didn't work either.  Why attach your functions to the global window object?  It's a poor practice.  I attach my functions to my own objects and limit scope and access through closures.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with the code there. Just replace `window['somefunc'](['a','b'])` with `somefunc.apply(window, ['a', 'b'])`. I don't see any reason why I shouldn't attach my `javascript` functions to `window` object, except you've called it "poor practice", which I can't understand why, so I still don't consider it a strong reason. Why `checkEmail(str)` function, which validates is a string an email, for example, should be attached to some object, but not `window`?

Comment: http://icant.co.uk/articles/seven-rules-of-unobtrusive-javascript/#r6    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript     http://www.slideshare.net/cheilmann/javascript-best-practices-1041724     Good luck.

Comment: understand, but OOP is good when it's good. I can overwrite your object as well. `x = { init : function() { alert('init!'); } }; x = 1`. I use objects when I need to. Common-purposes function should be attached to `window` object. Just my opinion. And I've never suffered from my approach. Still, I'm not `convinced`. I'm not stubborn though. Just need more strong argumentation rather then just "your functions can be overwritten".

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Answer:** You can now <sup>(Firefox=2012, Chrome=2015, Safari=2016)</sup> do this with a [`rest` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function someFunction(first, ...extra) {
    console.log(`You started with "${first}"`);
    extra.forEach(arg => console.log(arg));
}

someFunction(1, 2, 3);
```

As noted in [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770396/519360), there's an implicit [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object, but [`arguments` has some limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object). Notably, `arguments` contains all arguments and isn't a real array while `rest` parameters are a true array and intentionally omit any previously named arguments. The above example uses [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which won't work on `arguments`.

See also [`spread` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), introduced at the same time, for other uses of this dot-dot-dot-variable notation.