# Call a function with variable number of parameters

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass arbitrary number of parameters into Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770339/pass-arbitrary-number-of-parameters-into-javascript-function)

How can the following be achieved with n arguments?

```
function aFunction() {

    if ( arguments.length == 1 ) {
        anotherFunction( arguments[0] );
    } else if ( arguments.length == 2 ) {
        anotherFunction( arguments[0], arguments[1] );
    } else if ( arguments.length == 3 ) {
        anotherFunction( arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2] );
    }

}

function anotherFunction() {
    // got the correct number of arguments
}
```

Comment: Mayby the first argument an number with the amout of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this. Here is how you can call it without caring how many arguments you have:

```
function aFunction() {
    anotherFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}

function anotherFunction() {
    // got the correct number of arguments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call a function providing arguments as an array or array-like object:

```
function aFunction() {
    anotherFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

(If you check the MDN doco I linked to you'll see it mentions your specific example of passing all of a function's arguments to some other function, though obviously there are many other applications.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). This method on the `Function`'s prototype allows you to call a function with a specified `this` context, and pass the arguments as an array or an array-like object.

```
anotherFunction.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function aFunction() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    anotherFunction.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Why do you bother turning the `arguments` into a real array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Sample function...

```
functionName = function() {
   alert(arguments.length);//Arguments length.           
}
```