# How set variable externally resp. avoid globals?

Tags: javascript

I've got a variable in a js script, which I want to set from a php script and access from my js script.

How can I do this in good coding style manner.

At the moment I use a global variable in the js script for that purpose :(

Setting the variable from PHP:

```
$js = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$js .= "g_sourceType = '$sourcetype';";
$js .= "</script>\n";
```

Defining and accessing it in my js script:

```
var g_sourceType; // at global scope

...

function SetSubmitFocus()
{
  switch (g_sourceType) {
...
```

Comment: Is that an external javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @ChristianGraf:did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Check If this might help

```
$js = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$js .= "(function() {
        g_sourceType = function() {
        return '$sourcetype';
        };   
        })();";
$js .= "</script>\n";
```

Comment: Well, I want to *set* my global from outside

Comment: any particular reason you are doing this???there may be a better way..please elaborate the context of your problem..or is it just r and d stuff!!!

Comment: Well, quite easy:
I've got a `$_POST` variable that I evaluate in my PHP script. From this evaluation results the (value of the) `$sourcetype' variable whose value I need in my js script, too.

Comment: and what does your javascript looks like,can i see that??