# Why the variable value from is not accessible in following code snippet?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, alert

I've following Javascript code snippet :

```
authData=ref.getAuth();

if(authData == null){
    //TODO find an elegant way to manage authorization 
    //  window.location = "../index.html";
} else {
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot){
      $( "span.user-name").html(snapshot.val().displayName);    
      loggedInUser.displayName = snapshot.val().displayName;
      //alert("Name inside : "+loggedInUser.displayName);
      //Here it displays the value      
    });         
}

alert("Nameada is out : "+loggedInUser.displayName);
//Here it shows 'undefined'
```

**why?**

I want to use the variable value `loggedInUser.displayName` where did I shown alert.

Can someone please help me in accessing the value and displaying the alert?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that authData really isn't null? the getAuth() call could return null and then that variable is never initialized.

Comment: I don't see a declaration for the `loggedInUser` variable. Where is it? Your variable might be outside the correct scope.

Comment: @YasserElsayed, ray : all these things are present and have been initialized in other code files which also have been included. Please don't worry about it and consider they are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your final `alert` is executed when the callback function (`function(snapshot){ ... }`) has not yet been called. Note that the callback function is called asynchronously, so it only gets executed after the currently running code has completed and the `value` event is triggered.

This also explains why the inner (commented out) `alert` does work. Just realise that this piece of code (the call back function) is executed *later* than the other `alert`, even though it occurs earlier in your code.

You could "solve" it by calling another function from within the call back, like this:

```
authData=ref.getAuth();

if(authData == null){
    //TODO find an elegant way to manage authorization 
    //  window.location = "../index.html";
} else {
    ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot){
        $( "span.user-name").html(snapshot.val().displayName);    
        loggedInUser.displayName = snapshot.val().displayName;
        whenUserLogged();
    });         
}

function whenUserLogged() {
   alert("Name : "+loggedInUser.displayName);
   // anything else you want to do....
}
```

#### Some suggestions for improvement

Don't use [too many global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript) (in your code all of them are global), and instead pass variables as function arguments.

You may want to look into [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

Comment: Tell me how should I access the variable?

Comment: You can access the variable inside the callback function. Alternatively, you can call a function at that place, and output the variable in that new function.