# I can't use my function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting error with my function change_slide(). 
`ReferenceError: change_slide is not defined` on line 24:1.
My code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function change_slide() {
        number = pclass.charAt(6);
        number = parseInt(number);

        if (number == 5) number = 1;
        else number++;

        $('.picks').removeClass(pclass);
        pclass = 'bgpick' + number;
        $('.picks').addClass(pclass);
    }

    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    var pclass = 'bgpick' + random;
    var number;
    $('.picks').addClass(pclass);
    setInterval('change_slide()', 3000);
    $('.next').on('click', function() {
        change_slide();
    });
});
```

change_slide() on click .next works, in setInterval doesn't work.

Comment: take the function declaration outside of `.ready()`.

Comment: Have you tried to move the definition of change_slide outside of $(document).ready( .. )

Comment: I thought setInterval takes a function, not the name of a function. Try just changing it to `setInterval(change_slide, 3000)`

Comment: Yeah move it out of the ready. It can definitely take both a string or a function pointer.

Comment: Changing it to `setInterval(change_slide, 3000)` will work. But the problem is when you pass setInterval a string, it calls `eval` on the string in the global scope, and `change_slide` is only defined within `document.ready`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, either is acceptable syntactically. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: @DannyBuonocore Hmm, never knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a character string argument to `setInterval`, the Javascript code is executed in the global environment. You should pass a function reference instead of a character string, then it will be evaluated in the local environment.

```
setInterval(change_slide, 3000);
```

Note that you should *not* put parentheses after `change_slide` here. That will call the function immediately, instead of passing a reference to the function.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function declaration out of `document ready function`,

Also **change**

```
setInterval('change_slide()', 3000);
```

**To**

```
setInterval(change_slide, 3000);
```

Here is **modified** code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
  var pclass = 'bgpick' + random;
  var number;
  $('.picks').addClass(pclass);
  setInterval(change_slide, 3000);
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    change_slide();
  });
});
function change_slide() {
  number = pclass.charAt(6);
  number = parseInt(number);

  if (number == 5) number = 1;
  else number++;

  $('.picks').removeClass(pclass);
  pclass = 'bgpick' + number;
  $('.picks').addClass(pclass);
}
```

Comment: The first sentence is the correct answer. The rest of this answer is not needed.

Comment: No, taking the function out of the `ready` will create a global. Don't fall into this trap. The solution is to not use a string, so that it isn't tied to global scope.

Comment: revert _what_ stupidity - the second piece of code is broken. Supporting that is not wise

Comment: @Vld: I got at bit blind. i didnt see it was the invocation. apologies

Comment: @JonathanM The first sentence fixes it, but it is bad practice.

Comment: @4castle, can you explain that a bit? I might agree with you.

Comment: @JonathanM It creates a global function. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1841916/5743988) shows how to avoid that practice. Using `.ready()` is another way to avoid making a global.