# Prevent form submission during key press

Tags: javascript, forms

here i have a form with a text area.I had a keyup event attach to the text area.While giving input t o the text area with one finger i press down the key and with other hand i click the submit button.So the scenario is the form gets submitted while giving input to the text area.How can i prevent that from happening ?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action='sample.php' method='post'>
<input type='text' id='mytext' value=''>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('mytext').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    console.log("keyup");
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use validation and/or an `onsubmit` handler.

Comment: tried that...validation is used to check only numeric input...i can press and hold down any number key and submit the form as well

Comment: I don't know why? `keyup` event not trigger form submission.Then why & what you are ask to prevent  that? [see the fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d558wrte/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign `true` to a variable in the keydown event.

Assign `false` to it in the keyup event.

Test the value of it in the submit event and call `preventDefault` if it is `true`.

Comment: can you please elaborate :\..so i need a global variable...that could create problem...i am trying to avoid globals

Comment: What don't you understand? Your code demonstrates that you know how to assign event handlers. Assigning a value to a variable shouldn't be difficult. What's the problem?

Comment: You can use a closure / IIFE to avoid the use of a global. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1841941/19068

Answer (score 0):

This will not allow submit for 3 seconds after last keypress. In your `keyup` event, you set `canSubmit` to `false`, and then set a timeout with `setTimeout` that waits 3000 milliseconds, and then sets the value back to `true`.

Then you add another event listener to the form, which checks if `canSubmit` is `false`, and calls `event.preventDefault()`, which ends the event there.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action='sample.php' method='post' id="myForm">
    <input type='text' id='mytext' value=''>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
    <script>
    var canSubmit = true;
    document.getElementById('mytext').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
        canSubmit = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            canSubmit = true;
        }, 3000);
    });
    document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        if (!canSubmit) {
            return e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```