# How to update variable in the JS file from a child aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, deck.js

I have a JS file with below code. I need to update the value of variable **currentIndex** from my child aspx page. Right now this js refrence is over a parent page. I would like to know how to do it. What syntax should be passed from child.aspx page to have the updated value of currentIndex everywhere.

```
(function($, global, undefined) {
  var slides, currentIndex, $container, $fragmentLinks;

  var events = {
...
     prev: function() {
       methods.go(currentIndex-1);
     },
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose a function that will modify the `currentIndex` variable to global scope. But this approach does not scale well and should be considered as bad practice, because it could cause name clashes and other downsides. [How to avoid global variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript). So if you need to access parent page from child iframes you should think of better approach like communication through messages https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566923/2138959 or similar custom implementation.

For the time being the easiest way to solve your problem to define a setter function that will update `currentIndex` variable:

```
(function($, undefined) {
  var slides, currentIndex, $container, $fragmentLinks;

  window.setCurrentIndex = function(indexValue) {
    currentIndex = indexValue;
  };

  var events = {
...
     prev: function() {
       methods.go(currentIndex-1);
     },
...
```

And if you want to set index to value `3` for instance you could do:

```
window.setCurrentIndex(3);
```

Comment: hi Andrii, It says Unable to set property 'setCurrentIndex' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @AnkitKumar, I assumed you pass window as global to wrapper function. I have updated my answer.