# Is there a way to insert the pathname of the current page into a div class parameter value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert the name of the currently accessed webpage into a specific location in a `div` parameter value.

For example in the code below, I want to insert the page name (pathname) where you see `current_page_pathname`.

```
<div data-url="https://somedomain.com?source=current_page_pathname"></div>
```

I've looked at using `var current_page_pathname=window.location.pathname;`, but I don't know how to insert the `var` value where I want it.

If the currently accessed webpage is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth`, I want the `data-url` value to be:

```
<div data-url="https://somedomain.com?source=/wiki/Sloth"></div>
```

Is this possible?

Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm open to any solution that works.

Comment: Yes you can do this, and I could answer how. But, let me ask this: why? What are you trying to accomplish by storing something back into the html in this way?

Comment: Thank you for asking @MichaelMcQuade! I am using the `current_page_pathname` as an identifier. When the user clicks a button on the web page, I want to record that event and identify that it happened on the currently accessed page. This is a format required by an integration I'm using. Does that help? Thank you again!

Comment: @jhaaaa that does sound a bit strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it dynamically with javascript / jQuery

```js
$('#urlholderlink').attr('href', 'https://somedomain.com?source=' + window.location.pathname);
$('#urlholder').attr('data-url', 'https://somedomain.com?source=' + window.location.pathname);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="urlholderlink">My link</a>
<div id="urlholder">My div</div>
```

NB : in this snippet the url is relative to embedded document.

Comment: Note that jQuery has a `.data()` method that you can use instead of `.attr()` ... `element.data('url', 'https://somedomain.com/etc.../');` will create a `data-url` attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much @sinsedrix! This worked perfectly. I'm a total newbie -- so I appreciated your straightforward approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using the url of the embedded page:

```
https://stacksnippets.net/js
```

the following demo illustrates how you may do so with JavaScript:

```js
( function() {

let w = window;
let d = document;

let target_url = "https://www.example.com?source";
let curr_page_path = w.location.pathname;
 
// shortcut to access elements
let $ =  id =>  d.getElementById( id );
 
let atag = $("urlholderlink");
let div  = $("urlholder");

w.onload = function(){
  atag.href = (div.dataset.url =
      target_url + curr_page_path);

  let message = "DIV attribute data-url: " + div.dataset.url;
  message += '\n<a href="' + atag.href + '">';

  div.onclick = function() {
    console.log( message );
    atag.className="viewable";
    this.onclick=function(){
      return null; //disable div click
    }; // this.onclick 
  };// div.onclick 
}; // w.onload
})();// IFFE
```

```css
a {
  float: right;
  padding-right:80px;
  width:50px;
  color:#00f;
  visibility:hidden;
}

a:hover {
   text-decoration:overline;
}

#urlholder {
  cursor:default;
  margin-top:10%;
  color:lime;
  background:#000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 36px;
  font: 32px Arial,Helvetica;
  border: 15px outset #060;
}

#urlholder:hover {
  color:cyan;
}


.viewable {
 visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<a id="urlholderlink">My link</a>

<div id="urlholder" title="click for more info">My div</div>
```

The code takes advantage of the Window's onload event to call a handler, namely an anonymous  function that accesses the A and DIV elements.  It adds a `data-url` attribute to the DIV element and sets its value, using the [HTML5 datalist API](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/). The value of that assignment expression is in turn assigned as the value for the A element's `href` attribute.

The crux to setting these values simply involves concatenating `target_url` with  `curr_page_path`;

The source for the  immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) syntax comes from:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1843504/701302

The CSS is, of course optional --  added it for fun.

Comment: instead of polluting `document` with a `gt` method, rather create some scoped reusable helper function

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain JavaScript.

1. Query all div having a `data-url` attribute containing the placholder `current_page_pathname`. For this use `document.querySelectorAll('[data-url*="current_page_pathname"]')`
2. Use `forEach` to iterate over each node. Use `getAttribute('data-url')` and `setAttribute('data-url', newValue)` to update the attribute, and use `String.prototype.replace()` to replace the placeholder by the current url.

```js
const placeholder = 'current_page_pathname';

document.querySelectorAll(`[data-url*="${placeholder}"]`).forEach(node => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const dataUrl = node.getAttribute('data-url').replace(placeholder, path);
  node.setAttribute('data-url', dataUrl)
});

function show(e) {
  console.log(e.getAttribute('data-url'));
}
```

```css
div[data-url] {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div data-url="https://somedomain.com?source=current_page_pathname" onclick="show(this)">
  Click me to view my data-url attribute
</div>
<div data-url="https://somedomain.com?source=current_page_pathname" onclick="show(this)">
  Click me to view my data-url attribute
</div>
```