# Good practices for 'global' variables in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Recently I started developing some extensions for Chrome. I am doing this in manifest v3 and vanilla javascript. I have managed to make my extensions work. However, part of the fun of creating them is in learning to code better. I have been wondering whether I am handling variables in a correct way.

I have some data that I like to access from various points in my extension. Some of it is loaded dynamically and some I set in the code directly, like this:

```
const myExtensionData = {
  someData: [],
  config: [],
  links: [],
}
```

**1) Is it a good idea to store often-used data in a variable like myExtensionData.someData? Is there a better alternative?**

`myExtensionData.someData` is loaded from externally at some point in time. As I use this data in various functions, I have exposed it like this, so that I don't have to pass the data every time. I could use the local storage, but I have been holding that back as that requires another permission.

**2) Same question, but this time with stuff that is rarely used (myExtensionData.config)?**

The data in `myExtensionData.config` is also created dynamically, but the contents are not used as much. For example: I store whether one of my other extensions is also installed. If it is, I enable a button to access it from the popup. Rather single-use.

**3) How about static variables? (myExtensionData.links)?**

I keep some links I use for onUpdate, onInstall and for release notes. They change regularly, so I needed to store them somewhere. How about storing them in myExtensionData (I actually keep them in a global const at the moment).

**4) Any pointers are appreciated!**
I hope this is a worthy question. It's not very specific at all, but I am sure I can learn a lot here. I have searched for good practices/best practices, but they are usually outside the context of extension. If I have been looking at all the wrong places, please let me know.

## Trying to answer my own question

I found some interesting stuff in this [very old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841916/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-javascript). As I understand it, it's not a bad thing to store a variable in an object. Additionally, I like that it is also suggested to add some methods to the object as well.